# AWS lambda not starting my spring boot application server

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-lambda

I am deploying my spring boot applications in AWS lambda, but it seems like the initialization time of my application is more than 10 secs (greater than AWS lambda default time) so i am using async initialization of lambda handler using this link : https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-java-container/wiki/Quick-start---Spring-Boot2

I am using the above mentioned link code to initialize my spring boot application which is deployed on aws lambda but my server is not getting started. even though I have set the initialization 20 secs more but still getting the error.

my logs are this:

```
> Spring Boot : (v2.7.9)
> 2023-03-04 12:48:46,423 \[INFO\] org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication \[Thread-0\] Starting application using Java 1.8.0_322 on 169.254.104.9 with PID 8 (started by sbx_user1051 in /var/task)
> 2023-03-04 12:48:46,424 \[INFO\] org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication \[Thread-0\] No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
> 2023-03-04 12:48:47,157 \[INFO\] org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate \[Thread-0\] Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
> 2023-03-04 12:48:47,264 \[INFO\] org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate \[Thread-0\] Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 96 ms. Found 5 JPA repository interfaces.
> 2023-03-04 12:48:47,657 \[INFO\] com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.internal.servlet.AwsServletContext \[Thread-0\] Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
> 2023-03-04 12:48:47,657 \[INFO\] org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext \[Thread-0\] Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1187 ms
> 2023-03-04 12:48:47,895 \[INFO\] org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper \[Thread-0\] HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo \[name: default\]
> 2023-03-04 12:48:47,963 \[INFO\] org.hibernate.Version \[Thread-0\] HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.15.Final
> 2023-03-04 12:48:48,154 \[INFO\] org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version \[Thread-0\] HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
> 2023-03-04 12:48:48,267 \[INFO\] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource \[Thread-0\] HikariPool-1 - Starting...
> 2023-03-04 12:48:50,739 \[INFO\] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource \[Thread-0\] HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
> 2023-03-04 12:48:50,777 \[INFO\] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect \[Thread-0\] HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect
> 2023-03-04 12:48:54,898 \[INFO\] com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.AsyncInitializationWrapper \[main\] Initialization took longer than 10000, setting new CountDownLatch and continuing in event handler
> START RequestId: 6db605fe-4254-4773-9a79-f65851201865 Version: $LATEST
> 2023-03-04 12:48:54,904 \[INFO\] com.marketplaceupdater.jimintegration.StreamLambdaHandler \[main\] hi from handleRequest
> 2023-03-04 12:49:14,931 \[ERROR\] com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.internal.LambdaContainerHandler \[main\] Error while handling request
> com.amazonaws.serverless.exceptions.ContainerInitializationException: Could not initialize framework within the 20000ms timeout
> at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.internal.LambdaContainerHandler.proxy(LambdaContainerHandler.java:210)
> at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.internal.LambdaContainerHandler.proxyStream(LambdaContainerHandler.java:257)
> at com.marketplaceupdater.jimintegration.StreamLambdaHandler.handleRequest(StreamLambdaHandler.java:50)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader$StreamMethodRequestHandler.handleRequest(EventHandlerLoader.java:356)
> at lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader$2.call(EventHandlerLoader.java:903)
> at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.startRuntime(AWSLambda.java:349)
> at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.(AWSLambda.java:70)
> at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
> at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
> at lambdainternal.LambdaRTEntry.main(LambdaRTEntry.java:150)
> 2023-03-04 12:49:14,932 \[ERROR\] com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.AwsProxyExceptionHandler \[main\] Called exception handler for:
> com.amazonaws.serverless.exceptions.ContainerInitializationException: Could not initialize framework within the 20000ms timeout
> at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.internal.LambdaContainerHandler.proxy(LambdaContainerHandler.java:210)
> at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.internal.LambdaContainerHandler.proxyStream(LambdaContainerHandler.java:257)
> at com.marketplaceupdater.jimintegration.StreamLambdaHandler.handleRequest(StreamLambdaHandler.java:50)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader$StreamMethodRequestHandler.handleRequest(EventHandlerLoader.java:356)
> at lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader$2.call(EventHandlerLoader.java:903)
> at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.startRuntime(AWSLambda.java:349)
> at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.(AWSLambda.java:70)
> at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
> at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
> at lambdainternal.LambdaRTEntry.main(LambdaRTEntry.java:150)
> com.amazonaws.serverless.exceptions.ContainerInitializationException: Could not initialize framework within the 20000ms timeout
> at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.internal.LambdaContainerHandler.proxy(LambdaContainerHandler.java:210)
> at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.internal.LambdaContainerHandler.proxyStream(LambdaContainerHandler.java:257)
> at com.marketplaceupdater.jimintegration.StreamLambdaHandler.handleRequest(StreamLambdaHandler.java:50)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader$StreamMethodRequestHandler.handleRequest(EventHandlerLoader.java:356)
> at lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader$2.call(EventHandlerLoader.java:903)
> at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.startRuntime(AWSLambda.java:349)
> at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.(AWSLambda.java:70)
> at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
> at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
> at lambdainternal.LambdaRTEntry.main(LambdaRTEntry.java:150)
> END RequestId: 6db605fe-4254-4773-9a79-f65851201865
> REPORT RequestId: 6db605fe-4254-4773-9a79-f65851201865 Duration: 20044.48 ms Billed Duration: 20045 ms Memory Size: 2048 MB Max Memory Used: 270 MB Init Duration: 9902.12 ms
```

This is my Lambda handler class:

```java
public class StreamLambdaHandler implements RequestStreamHandler {
    private SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler<AwsProxyRequest, AwsProxyResponse> handler;

    Logger logger= LoggerFactory.getLogger(StreamLambdaHandler.class);

    public StreamLambdaHandler() throws ContainerInitializationException {
        try {
            long startTime = Instant.now().toEpochMilli();
            logger.info("setting initialisation time -20sec begins");
            // by setting this value to 20_000 the framework will wait for an additional 20 seconds
            // on top of the default 10 initialization time.
            LambdaContainerHandler.getContainerConfig().setInitializationTimeout(20_000);

            logger.info("setting initialisation time -20sec ends ");

            handler = new SpringBootProxyHandlerBuilder<AwsProxyRequest>()
                    .defaultProxy()
                    .asyncInit()
                    .springBootApplication(JimIntegrationApplication.class)
                    .buildAndInitialize();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void handleRequest(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, Context context)
            throws IOException {

        logger.info("hi from handleRequest ");

        handler.proxyStream(inputStream, outputStream, context);
    }
```

Comment: Possible advice [here](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-java-container/wiki/Quick-start---Spring-Boot).

Comment: i have used the same link but still causes the problem ... my spring boot server is not getting started

Comment: now after some changes i am not getting connection time out exception but getting this : my server still not getting started
2023-03-05 05:44:42,569 [INFO] org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version [main] HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2023-03-05 05:44:42,683 [INFO] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource [main] HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-03-05 05:44:45,032 [INFO] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource [main] HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-03-05 05:44:45,065 [INFO] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect [main] HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the error is in the supplied code, but hidden somewhere else. (Also the log messages you are showing in the handler are not included in the logs.)

I guess spring is trying to do something that takes longer than 20s, maybe trying connecting to a DB which it doesn't has access to?

Try setting the timeout to 15m and starting it again in the hope that the other task times out and you can see what the issue is.